Retopologizing Hard Surface Model - Controlling Solidify
While retopologizing a model for 3D printing, I'm running into some issues with solidifying the mesh. Since I'm going to be printing this I obviously can't leave as 2d planes. However, I'm also going to have to break the model up into parts for printing, and I don't want to have them in solid chunks because there's going to be places I'm going to be putting some interior details (landing gear wells, cockpit, maintenance spaces, open engine bays, etc).
I figured the easiest way to get uniform thickness would be with a Solidify modifier, however this has a particular problem:

The Solidify modifier tries to keep the extruded edges perpendicular to the source mesh, however there's places where this doesn't work for me. For example, the lower half of the hull needs to be able to meet flush with the upper half, so I want that joint to be flat, as noted in the red.

In other places, I want the vertical edges to be at an angle, rather than straight, as shown in red here.
Is there a way that the Solidify modifier can be controlled in this manner? Or should I just complete the entire mesh as one piece first, solidify it, and then cut it up into parts?
